# specific element parsing from xml files in windows phone 8

Tags: xml, parsing, windows-phone-8, data-binding, linq-to-xml

Hello I am building an app that in it's MainPage.xaml gets an xml file(categories.xml) and using data binding I generate dynamic hubtiles, which are the categories, and in case of the device is not connected to the network, I save it and call it to/from the Isolated Storage.

Pressing a dynamic tile it navigates to another page named BusinessList.xaml and downloads/loads with the same way a new xml file (businesses.xml) containing the business details of each category.

My problem now is that pressing any tile,I get all the businesses but I want to be able to get the categoryID from the categories.xml file and compare it to the categoryID that is a foreign key to the businesses.xml and tell it to show me the business details of the same categoryID.(the server is mine).

MainPage.xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tileList">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:HubTile 
                                     Tag="{Binding categoryID}"            
                                     Margin="25" 
                                     Title="{Binding categoryName}" 
                                     Source="{Binding image}"                                       
                                     Tap="Selection_Tap">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu1">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="SelectionPin_Hold"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:HubTile>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Δεν βρέθηκε σύνδεση! Θα φορτωθεί το αρχείο που κατέβηκε την τελευταία φορά, το οποίο μπορεί να μην είναι ανανεωμένο.");
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("categories.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new
                        XmlSerializer(typeof(Categories));
                        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                        Categories categories = (Categories)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                        tileList.ItemsSource = categories.Collection;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Δεν υπάρχει κάποιο κατεβασμένο αρχείο!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://myip/categories.php", UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new
            DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(CategoriesDownloaded);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
    }
    void CategoriesDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Υπήρξε σφάλμα στο κατέβασμα των δεδομένων!");
            }
            else
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new
                XmlSerializer(typeof(Categories));
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                Categories categories = (Categories)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                tileList.ItemsSource = categories.Collection;

                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("categories.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
                    {
                        document.Save(isoStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The same way is Businesses.xaml and Businesses.xaml.cs:

Now I have found that piece of code get me the categoryID

```
string holdElement = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(sender)).Tag.ToString();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BusinessList.xaml?msg=" + holdElement, UriKind.Relative));
```

And with this piece of code I get it to the other page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string queryStringValue = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out queryStringValue))
        {
            string categoryID = queryStringValue;

            switch (categoryID)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I know my thinking is not entirely correct but I can't think of another way than this. I'm trying make a switch that get's the categoryID and with cases of the number to be able to parse the correct businesses but I don't know what I have to write inside.
Maybe someone can tell me a better way or what I can put inside this switch?

Edit:

```
    [XmlRoot("root")]
public class Businesses
{
    [XmlArray("businesses")]
    [XmlArrayItem("business")]
    public ObservableCollection<Business> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
    [XmlElement("businessID")]
    public string businessID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("categoryID")]
    public string categoryID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("phone")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("deliveryTime")]
    public string deliveryTime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("isActive")]
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("categoryName")]
    public string categoryName { get; set; }

}
```

The xml looks like :

```
<root>
 <businesses>
  <business>
   ....
  </business>
 ....
 </businesses>
</root>
```

Comment: Without knowing how the xml looks like and the model class to represent each "business", I can only suggest a general advice : use LINQ-to-XML to filter the XML

Comment: @har07 I edited my post. Thanks for your answer. I'm new to xml parsing and it's kinda hard for me to search something specific if I don't know what it is. I thought LINQ-to-XML was only downloading/loading the xml but it makes sense now if you say I can filter the results. Could you probably give me an example or a site I could search for examples/tutorials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time and efford but I had the answer for what I wanted in front of me the whole time. All I did was to declare a variable at the beginning of my BusinessList.xaml page

```
private string categoryID = "";
```

and then remove the declaration of categoryID from my OnNavigatedTo method,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string queryStringValue = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out queryStringValue))
    {
         categoryID = queryStringValue;
    }
}
```

and then on my listbox on BusinessList.xaml i would change this

```
sI.ItemsSource = businesses.Collection;
```

to this

```
 sI.ItemsSource = businesses.Collection.Where(c => c.categoryID == categoryID).ToList();
```

What you wrote is almost the same as what I wrote, so I believe that its possible your code does the same thing as mine, so I could probably have used your way if I haven't found it myself.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, you can use LINQ-to-XML without deserializing the XML, for example :

```
string categoryID = queryStringValue;
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
Businesses filteredBusinesses = new Businesses();

filteredBusinesses.Collection = 
        new ObservableCollection<Business>
        (
            document.Descendants("business")
                    .Where(o => (string)o.Element("categoryID") == categoryID)
                    .Select(o => new Business
                     {
                         businessID = (string)o.Element("businessID"),
                         categoryID = (string)o.Element("categoryID") == categoryID),
                         .....
                         .....
                     }
        );
```

The downside of this approach is you need to manually map each property of `Business` object to corresponding XML element.

Another possible way is to deserialize the XML to `Businesses` object, then filter the deserialization result using LINQ-to-Object :

```
string categoryID = queryStringValue;

Businesses allBusinesses;
//here deserialize businesses.xml to allBusinesses variable

Businesses filteredBusinesses = new Businesses();
filteredBusinesses.Collection = 
        new ObservableCollection<Business>
        (
            allBusinesses.Collection
                         .Where(o => o.categoryID == categoryID)
        );
```